# Undefined property in dynamic variable of a PHP class

Tags: php

I am trying to get a dynamic variable value in a PHP class but not sure how to do this. Here's my code:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $type = "added";

    public $date_added;

    public function set_status()
    {
        $this->date_added = "Pass";
    }

    public function get_status()
    {
        echo $this->date_{$type};
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->set_status();
$test->get_status();
?>
```

I am getting following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Test::$date_ in...

Notice: Undefined variable: type in ...
```

If I write `echo $this->date_added;` in place of `echo $this->date_{$type};` then I get output "Pass".

How to fix it and do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using variable variables, put them in quotes, then concatenate:

```
echo $this->{'date_' . $this->type};
                    // not $type, use `$this->` since it's part of your properties
```

Or using via formatted string *(double quotes will work as well)*:

```
echo $this->{"date_{$this->type}"};
```

Comment: So it is called variable of a variable or dynamic variable? Single quotes will not work in your second syntax?

Comment: @Sachin yes, that's what PHP calls it. if you use single quotes on the second version, you'll get the literal `date_{$this->type}`. you need to interpolate the value from `$this->type` to get `date_added`, and via double quotes it is possible

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $type = "added";

    public $date_added;

    public function set_status()
    {
        $this->date_added = "Pass";
    }

    public function get_status()
    {
        echo $this->{'date_' . $this->type};
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->set_status();
$test->get_status();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways, `date_{$type}` is not valid expression and to acccess the class property you have to use `this` keyword .

```
class Test
{
    public $type = "added";

    public $date_added;

    public function set_status()
    {
        $this->date_added = "Pass";
    }

    public function get_status()
    {
        $prop = 'date_'.$this->type;

        echo $this->{'date_'.$this->type}; # one way to do it
        echo $this->$prop;                  # another way to do it
        echo $this->{"date_{$this->type}"}; # another way to do it
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->set_status();
$test->get_status();
```

Comment: What is `$prop`? Please explain.

Comment: $prop is just another variable that holds the actual property value as string, this is a good practice when you have to do some calculation/concatenation/operation to make the final property name like here. `$prop = 'date_'.$this->type;`

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks.